# Visual Studio Community 2017 linker problems - MariaDB

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, mariadb, linker-errors

Its my first foray into messing with DB's in programming (specifically MariaDB) in Visual Studio and am not having much luck. It looks like I have configured external linking incorrectly however I am staring at my settings and just not seeing the error. Its probably going to be obvious to more experienced coders out there but I can't see the forest because of the trees.

I have tried compiling in both x86 and 64bit with their respective libraries. I've only included the x86 settings below but they are identical *APART* from pointing to "program files" instead of "program files x86"

My code is quite simple at the moment:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <mysql.h>

int main()
{
    MYSQL* temp;
    temp = mysql_init(NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

but when I try to compile I get the following output.

```
1>------ Build started: Project: test, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>test.cpp
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>mariadbclient.lib(mariadb_lib.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__ntohs@4 referenced in function _mysql_once_init
1>mariadbclient.lib(mariadb_lib.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__getservbyname@8 referenced in function _mysql_once_init
1>mariadbclient.lib(mariadb_lib.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PathRemoveExtensionA@4 referenced in function _mysql_optionsv
1>mariadbclient.lib(mariadb_lib.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PathStripPathA@4 referenced in function _mysql_optionsv
1>mariadbclient.lib(ma_init.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__WSAStartup@8 referenced in function _my_win_init
1>mariadbclient.lib(ma_init.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__WSACleanup@0 referenced in function _ma_end
1>mariadbclient.lib(ma_pvio.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__WSAGetLastError@0 referenced in function _ma_pvio_read_async
1>mariadbclient.lib(mariadb_async.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__WSAGetLastError@0
1>mariadbclient.lib(pvio_socket.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__WSAGetLastError@0
1>mariadbclient.lib(ma_default.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__PathRemoveFileSpecA@4 referenced in function _get_default_configuration_dirs
1>mariadbclient.lib(mariadb_async.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__connect@12 referenced in function _my_connect_async
1>mariadbclient.lib(pvio_socket.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__connect@12
1>mariadbclient.lib(mariadb_async.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__getsockopt@20 referenced in function _my_connect_async
1>mariadbclient.lib(pvio_socket.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp__getsockopt@20
1>mariadbclient.lib(pvio_socket.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___WSAFDIsSet@8 referenced in function _pvio_socket_wait_io_or_timeout
1>mariadbclient.lib(pvio_socket.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__bind@12 referenced in function _pvio_socket_connect
1>mariadbclient.lib(pvio_socket.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__closesocket@4 referenced in function _pvio_socket_connect
1>mariadbclient.lib(pvio_socket.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__ioctlsocket@12 referenced in function _pvio_socket_blocking
1>mariadbclient.lib(pvio_socket.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__recv@16 referenced in function _pvio_socket_async_read
1>mariadbclient.lib(pvio_socket.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__select@20 referenced in function _pvio_socket_wait_io_or_timeout
1>mariadbclient.lib(pvio_socket.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__send@16 referenced in function _pvio_socket_async_write
1>mariadbclient.lib(pvio_socket.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__setsockopt@20 referenced in function _pvio_socket_fast_send
1>mariadbclient.lib(pvio_socket.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__shutdown@8 referenced in function _pvio_socket_close
1>mariadbclient.lib(pvio_socket.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__socket@12 referenced in function _pvio_socket_connect
1>mariadbclient.lib(pvio_socket.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__WSASetLastError@4 referenced in function _pvio_socket_wait_io_or_timeout
1>mariadbclient.lib(pvio_socket.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__getaddrinfo@16 referenced in function _pvio_socket_connect
1>mariadbclient.lib(pvio_socket.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__freeaddrinfo@4 referenced in function _pvio_socket_connect
1>mariadbclient.lib(ma_schannel.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__CryptAcquireContextA@20 referenced in function _ma_schannel_load_private_key
1>mariadbclient.lib(ma_schannel.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__CryptReleaseContext@8 referenced in function _ma_schannel_load_private_key
1>mariadbclient.lib(ma_schannel.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__CryptDestroyKey@4 referenced in function _ma_schannel_load_private_key
1>mariadbclient.lib(ma_schannel.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__CryptImportKey@24 referenced in function _ma_schannel_load_private_key
1>d:\nikuya\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\test\Debug\test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 27 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "test.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

My settings are below -

```
VC++ Directories -> Include Directories -> C:\Program Files %28x86%29\MariaDB\MariaDB Connector C\include\mysql
VC++ Directories -> Include Directories -> C:\Program Files %28x86%29\MariaDB\MariaDB Connector C\include\mysql\include
VC++ Directories -> Library Directories -> C:\Program Files %28x86%29\MariaDB\MariaDB Connector C\lib
VC++ Directories -> Library Directories -> C:\Program Files %28x86%29\MariaDB\MariaDB Connector C\lib\plugin
C++ Directories -> Addition Include Directories -> C:\Program Files %28x86%29\MariaDB\MariaDB Connector C\include\mysql
C++ Directories -> Addition Include Directories -> C:\Program Files %28x86%29\MariaDB\MariaDB Connector C\include
Linker -> General -> Addition Library Directories -> C:\Program Files %28x86%29\MariaDB\MariaDB Connector C\lib\plugin
Linker -> General -> Addition Library Directories -> C:\Program Files %28x86%29\MariaDB\MariaDB Connector C\lib
Linker -> Additional Dependancies -> mariadbclient.lib
Linker -> Additional Dependancies -> libmariadb.lib
```

Any help would be appreciated and please ask if any further info is needed.

note: I also tried including windows.h out of desperation but no dice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key line here is:
`1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library`

You are attempting to use a library which is incompatible with libcmt which is the multithreaded c run time library.

It is likely that you are compiling with a different switch (often /MD or /MT) somewhere to what was used to build the mariadb libs.

See here for more info:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa267384(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: Makes sense and I have found the correct runtime library and the warning has now gone. However the linking errors remain.

Comment: You are missing some of the standard Windows API libs. Look up for example `closesocket` on MSDN and it will tell you which additional libraries to link with.

Comment: Thank you to both of you. Have got it sorted. Needed to find the functions on msdn and link to their individual libraries.